# my project schedule

Tags: tables

I need to do my project schedule like this.
[image]

Comment: You could either draw the table yourself (the nicematrix package would be my package of choice here) or use one of the packages dedicated to producing gantt charts.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: from my earlier answer -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/567391/197451

Answer (score 6):

Not elementary; a few tricks are in order.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\vrule height4ex width 0pt}p{#1}<{\vrule depth 2.5ex width 0pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|P{4cm}*{10}{|c}|}
\hline
\centering \raisebox{-2ex}[0pt][0pt]{Action plan} & \multicolumn{7}{c|}{2020} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{2021} \\
\cline{2-11}
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\vphantom{$\Big|$}} &
\scriptsize Jun & \scriptsize Jul & \scriptsize Aug & \scriptsize Sep &
\scriptsize Oct & \scriptsize Nov & \scriptsize Dec & \scriptsize Jan &
\scriptsize Feb & \scriptsize Mar \\
\hline
1. Study the theoretical background and review existing literature &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor{gray}} &&&&&&&& \\
\hline
2. Synthesis monoclinic VO\textsubscript{2} nanoparticle and prepare the thermocromic film &
&& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor{gray}} &&&&& \\
\hline
3. Determine the optical properties of the VO\textsubscript{2} thin film &
&&&& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor{gray}} &&& \\
\hline
4. Analysis of the experimental results &
&&&&&& \multicolumn{3}{c}{\cellcolor{gray}} & \\
\hline
5. Prepare the report and presentation &
&&&&& \multicolumn{5}{c}{\cellcolor{gray}} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here are some alternatives using `nicematrix` or `pgfgantt`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}

{\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.5pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}*{10}{c}}[hvlines]
\Block{2-1}{Action plan} & \Block{1-7}{2020} &&&&&&& \Block{1-3}{2021} \\
& \scriptsize Jun & \scriptsize Jul & \scriptsize Aug & \scriptsize Sep &
\scriptsize Oct & \scriptsize Nov & \scriptsize Dec & \scriptsize Jan &
\scriptsize Feb & \scriptsize Mar \\
1. Study the theoretical background and review existing literature &
\Block[fill=gray]{1-2}{}  \\
2. Synthesis monoclinic \ch{VO2} nanoparticle and prepare the thermocromic film &
&& \Block[fill=gray]{1-3}{} \\
3. Determine the optical properties of the \ch{VO2} thin film &
&&&& \Block[fill=gray]{1-3}{} \\
4. Analysis of the experimental results &
&&&&&& \Block[fill=gray]{1-3}{}  \\
5. Prepare the report and presentation &
&&&&& \Block[fill=gray]{1-5}{} \\
\end{NiceTabular}}


\begin{ganttchart}[
     y unit title=0.5cm,
     y unit chart=1.75cm,
     x unit =0.75cm,
     vgrid,hgrid,
     title height=1,
     title/.style={fill=none},
     title label font=\footnotesize,
     bar/.style={fill=gray},
     bar height=1,
     bar top shift=0,
     progress label text={},
     group right shift=0,
     group height=.6,
     group peaks width={0.2},
     inline, 
     bar label node/.style={text width=3.5cm,
                            align=right,
                            anchor=east,
                            font=\small}
    ]{1}{10}

  \gantttitle{2020}{7}
  \gantttitle{2021}{2} \\
              
  \gantttitle{Jun}{1} \gantttitle{Jul}{1} \gantttitle{Aug}{1} \gantttitle{Sep}{1} 
  \gantttitle{Oct}{1} \gantttitle{Nov}{1} \gantttitle{Dec}{1}
  \gantttitle{Jan}{1} \gantttitle{Feb}{1} \gantttitle{Mar}{1}\\
 
  \ganttbar[progress=100,inline=false]
      {1. Study the theoretical background and review existing literature}
      {1}{2}\\
  \ganttbar[progress=100,inline=false]
      {2. Synthesis monoclinic \ch{VO2} nanoparticle and prepare the thermocromic film}
      {3}{5}\\
  \ganttbar[progress=100,inline=false]
      {3. Determine the optical properties of the \ch{VO2} thin film}
      {5}{7} \\
  \ganttbar[progress=100,inline=false]
      {4. Analysis of the experimental results}
      {8}{9}\\ 
  \ganttbar[progress=100,inline=false]
      {5. Prepare the report and presentation}
      {6}{10} 
\end{ganttchart}


\end{document}
```