# How do I draw a horizontal line from column 2 to the end in longtable

Tags: tables

I have a longtable in landscape mode. In the second column I have a list of activities to be carried out over 12 weeks. I would like each activity to have a line drawn under it right to the end of the table. I want to do this so that I can color the cell under the appropriate action is to be carried out.
I wonder if this is possible. I have not been able to find any solution to this from the various SO posts I googled.
I would appreciate any feedback.
I attach my MWE

```
 \documentclass[11pt,twoside,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{enumerate,mdwlist}
\usepackage[usegeometry]{typearea}% load before geometry
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,vmargin=21mm,bindingoffset=12mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{boldline,multirow}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor} % Required to specify font color
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\begin{document}
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,DIV=last}
\newgeometry{hmargin=2.5cm,top=18mm,bottom=15mm,includehead}
\section{Work Timeline}
\textbf{\Large Problem solution process}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}%
\hfill{}
{
  \setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}
  \newcommand{\thinvrule}{{\vrule width 0.5pt}}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}% for the vertical padding
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt} % for the horizontal padding
  \begin{longtable}[H]{|p{4.6cm} | p{10cm} | *6{*3{p{0.7cm}!\thinvrule }p{0.7cm}|}}
\hline
& \textbf{\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad Months} &\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Nov.}&\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Dec.}&\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Jan.}\\
\hline
\textbf{Programme} & \textbf{Activities}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \textbf{Weeks} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12\\
\hline
\textbf{Problem analysis and solution}
&
\parbox{.95\linewidth}{
1.\quad Identify steps required to solve the problem using some known approaches as recommended in the manual\\
2.\quad Start the solution process\\
3.\quad Submit the solution for scrutiny
}
& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: as far as I can tell the standard `\cline` command is what you need? Why is this question tagged [tag:biblatex] ?

Comment: When I wrote latex, biblatex came, with pdflates and xelatex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're interested in somethign like the following:

[image]

```
 \documentclass[11pt,twoside,fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{enumerate,mdwlist}
\usepackage[usegeometry]{typearea}% load before geometry
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,vmargin=21mm,bindingoffset=12mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{boldline,multirow}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor} % Required to specify font color
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.5mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xltabular}


\begin{document}
\KOMAoptions{paper=landscape,DIV=last}
\newgeometry{hmargin=2.5cm,top=18mm,bottom=15mm,includehead}
\section{Work Timeline}
\textbf{\Large Problem solution process}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}%
\hfill{}
{
  \setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}
  \newcommand{\thinvrule}{{\vrule width 0.5pt}}
%  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}% for the vertical padding
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\makegapedcells
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt} % for the horizontal padding
  \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|X | p{10cm} | *6{*3{wc{0.7cm}!\thinvrule }wc{0.7cm}|}}
\hline
& \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\textbf{Months}} &\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Nov.}&\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Dec.}&\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Jan.}\\
\hline
\textbf{Programme} & \textbf{Activities}\hfill\textbf{Weeks} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12\\
\hline
\multirow{4}{=}{\textbf{Problem analysis and solution}}
& 1.\quad Identify steps required to solve the problem using some known approaches as recommended in the manual & & & & & & & & & & & & \\ \Xcline{2-14}{0.5pt}
& 2.\quad Start the solution process & & & & & & & & & & & & \\ \Xcline{2-14}{0.5pt}
& 3.\quad Submit the solution for scrutiny
& & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
\end{xltabular}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, @leandriis. Thank you very much you have saved my day.

Comment: Hello @leandriis I hope I can still reach you. The purpose of my splitting the cells as in the example you gave was for me to color some cells. I noticed that \cellcolor{blue!20}, e.g. in any cell does not work. Is this normal or is there any way around this?

Comment: @ZiloreMumba: In your original qquestion I totally missed the point that you wanted colored cells. The `\makegapedcells` command I used is incompatible with colored cells, hence you don't get the expected output. If you remove the mentioned command, you should get colored cells.

Comment: Since combining colored cells with lines may lead to the effet of "vanishing" lines, you may also want to consider using an alternative package for your table. For this it is important to know if your table will definitely spread across multiple pages. If that's the case, you may want to use `longtblr` from `tabularray`. If that's not the case and your table will fit onto a single package, you may want to use `tblr` from the `tabularray` package  or `NiceTabular` from the `nicematrix` package.

Comment: You could also use an entirely different package, namely the `pgfgantt` package. For an example you may want to take a look at this previous answer of mine: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579761/134144

Comment: Thanks very much, all works perfectly. Have a good day.